# Section in black box and in margin for all pages like in IBM Technical Manuals

Tags: header-footer, margins

I am trying to produce a vertical box with the word "Section" including its current section number on the outer margin of each page. This is to mimic the original IBM Technical Manuals. An example can be found below.
It should stay at the exact position on each page and be visible on each page accordingly. I am using the memoir class in my document.

[image: Original IBM Manual]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for - HUGE THANKS